# Figuring out why percentages always returns 0

Tags: swift

I am trying to figure out the percentages like so:

```
let percentages:CGFloat = CGFloat((result.count / 100) * 100)
```

But this always returns 0. What am I doing wrong?

`result.count` is 2.

Comment: **Integer divison**, `result.count / 100` will be an integer, more precise the integer `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're probably performing an integer division, so you need to convert that count to something else first:

```
let percentages = CGFloat(result.count) / 100 * 100
```

Notice, however that you're dividing and multiplying by the same value (100). You might need to tweak that too to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Why cast to `Double` then to `CGFloat`? Just use one cast, no explicit type, and far fewer parentheses: `let percentages = CGFloat(count) / 100 * 100`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, there's no need. Just edited my answer.

Comment: You don't need the `: CGFloat`.

Comment: `CGFloat` and `Float`, unlike `Double` will sometimes have problems calculating bigger numbers... I had a bug where dividing 13 billion something by 1 billion gave me 12.999999.... This is because Float doesn't have as many `bits` to work with.. Therefor `Double` should be used

Comment: Floating point precision is not really the point of the question. I just used the type originally used in the question.